# Referencing a button generated with map method in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is a rather oversimplified version of a problem I am dealing with, it has no practical application IRL.

What I want is to reference a 'green' button and set it to **blink for 3 seconds**. How can I do that in React?

```
const btnLayout = ["Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"];

btnLayout.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <button>
      data-id={`slot-${item}`}
      type="button" className={`col-1 btn btn-${colorMap[index]}`}
      {item}
    </button>
  );
});
```

Comment: does the value "green" lies only at 2nd position or it may vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ref to get access to the button node in the DOM, Please check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/refs-green-button-tgrdw).

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS animations for blinking effect and stop it using animation-iteration-count.

```
const btnLayout = ["Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Orange"];

btnLayout.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <button>
      data-id={`slot-${item}`}
      type="button" className={`col-1 btn btn-${colorMap[index]} ${item === "Green" ? "blink_me" : ""}`}
      {item}
    </button>
  );
});
```

CSS classes

```
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/refs-green-button-qorxu)